How to access PrimeNG Dropdown 's OverlayOptions OnBeforeShow Callback?
Is it possible to listen for a dropdowns overlay event that it is about to open?
the Dropdown's OverlayOptions offer OnBeforeShow Callback, but I am not able to use/access it.
Something like
<p-dropdown
  #dropdown
  (onBeforeShow)="doSomething()"
</p-dropdown>

Or
this.dropdown.overlayOptions.onBeforeShow((e) => {
  doSomething(e);
}

would be cool.

We need to access the view child of the overlay.
For this, we can use the property overlayViewChild
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { ImportsModule } from './imports';
import { Dropdown } from 'primeng/dropdown';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
interface City {
  name: string;
  code: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'dropdown-basic-demo',
  templateUrl: './dropdown-basic-demo.html',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [ImportsModule],
})
export class DropdownBasicDemo implements OnInit {
  private sub: Subscription = new Subscription();
  @ViewChild(Dropdown) pdropdown!: Dropdown;
  cities: City[] | undefined;

  selectedCity: City | undefined;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.cities = [
      { name: 'New York', code: 'NY' },
      { name: 'Rome', code: 'RM' },
      { name: 'London', code: 'LDN' },
      { name: 'Istanbul', code: 'IST' },
      { name: 'Paris', code: 'PRS' },
    ];
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.sub.add(
      this.pdropdown.overlayViewChild.onBeforeShow.subscribe((event: any) => {
        console.log('from listener', event);
      })
    );
  }

  doSomething() {
    console.log('something');
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.sub.unsubscribe();
  }
}

Stackblitz Demo
